# reset object position in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, computer-science

Trying to code the classic arcade game 'Pong', I've gotten stuck trying to reset the 'ball' into it's original position after the computer scores.

```
class Pong:

    def __init__(self, width, height, x,y, color, screenw, screenh):
            self.width = width
            self.height = height

            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.point = (self.x,self.y)

            self.color = color
            self.speed = random.randint(3,5)

            self.screenw = screenw
            self.screenh = screenh

            self.dx = random.choice([-2,-1,1,2])
            self.dy = random.choice([1,-1])

            self.compscore = 0
            self.playerscore = 0

            self.score = False


    def game_logic(self):
            x,y = self.point
            x += self.speed*self.dx
            y += self.speed*self.dy

            if x + self.width >= self.screenw:
                    self.dx = -1
                    self.color = GREEN
                    self.playerpoint()
                    print(str(self.playerscore)+" : "+str(self.compscore))
            if x <= 100:
                    self.dx = 1
                    self.color = WHITE
                    self.comppoint()
                    print(str(self.playerscore)+" : "+str(self.compscore))
            if y + self.height >= self.screenh:
                    self.dy = -1
                    self.color = ORANGE
            if y <= 0:
                    self.dy = 1
                    self.color = SALMON

            self.point = (x,y)
            return

    def resetpong(self):
        self.point = (200,200)
        self.dx = random.choice([-2,-1,1,2])
        self.dy = random.choice([1,-1])
        return self.point

    def comppoint(self):
            self.compscore += 1
            print("The computer has scored a point.")
            self.resetpong()
            return self.compscore

    def playerpoint(self):
            self.playerscore += 1
            print("Nice! You've scored a point.")
            self.resetpong()
            return self.playerscore
```

I've created the reset method and no matter where I've put it, whether in an if statement in the game_logic method in my pygame starter, or inside the game_logic in the Pong class. It does work though if I set it to a keybinding?
Am I an idiot?

Comment: Which variable represents the position of the ball?  If it's `self.point`, you don't modify that in the function `resetpong`.

Comment: Rip, that code is wrong. Yeah, I'm supposed to have self.point = (200,200) belove def resetpong(self)

Comment: But even so, having the code as it is still doesn't reset the ball.

Answer (score 0):

The function `resetpong` changes the value of `self.point`.  This function gets called by `playerpoint` or `comppoint`.  The call to `playerpoint` or `comppoint` occurs in the function `game_logic`.  This line at the end of `game_logic`:

```
self.point = (x,y)
```

therefore clobbers the new value of `self.point`.  A similar problem affects the variable `self.dx` which gets set in `game_logic` and then clobbered by a call to  `playerpoint` or `comppoint`.

Change the function `game_logic` as follows to fix both of these:

```
def game_logic(self):
        x,y = self.point
        x += self.speed*self.dx
        y += self.speed*self.dy
        self.point = x, y  # parenthesis not needed here

        if x + self.width >= self.screenw:
                self.color = GREEN
                self.playerpoint()
                print(str(self.playerscore)+" : "+str(self.compscore))
        elif x <= 100:   # elif here: only test this if previous if is false
                self.color = WHITE
                self.comppoint()
                print(str(self.playerscore)+" : "+str(self.compscore))
        if y + self.height >= self.screenh:
                self.dy = -1
                self.color = ORANGE
        elif y <= 0:  # elif here: only test this if previous if is false
                self.dy = 1
                self.color = SALMON

        # return not needed here
```

I also recommend removing the variables `self.x` and `self.y`from the Pong constructor since they are never used.  The variable self.point contains those numbers and it's a violation of a basic principle to keep the same information in two different places.